# How to define css to table td with attribute?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```
<td title="He is from KL working in Assyst at Kochi.Today Ind vs Aus match 2nd semi final Aus won the game India Lost">He is from....</td>
```

How can i give css to  above table column?
I tried like this but it doesn't work in asp.net grid view control with boundfield?

```
table, tr, td:title
{
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 10px;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

How can  resolve it?

Comment: check attribute selector (what you are using is called pseudo selector)

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: In grid view control no id used in bound field .Above given is inspected element

Answer (score 0):

Give the element an id.

For example

```
<td id="titleId" title="He is from KL working in Assyst at Kochi.Today Ind vs
     Aus match 2nd semi final Aus won the game India Lost">He is from....</td>

#titleId
{
background-color: #efefef;
padding: 10px;
color: red;
border: 1px solid blue;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: In grid view control no id used in bound field .Above given is inspected element

Answer (score -1):

You can try it as follows

```css
<td style="background-color: #efefef""padding: 10px""color: red""border: 1px solid blue""text-align: justify">
```